# select div from id and class jquery

Tags: jquery, class, html, show

I have this structure:

```
<div id="list_articles">
  <div id="article">
    <label>Select:</label><input type="checkbox" class="checked_art" id="1001" />
    <div id="hide" style="display:none;" class="1001">
      //Code here...
    /div>
  </div>
  <div id="article">
    <label>Select:</label><input type="checkbox" class="checked_art" id="1002" />
    <div id="hide" style="display:none;" class="1002">
      //Code here...
    /div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is that when I check my checkbox, get the "hide"  according to the checkbox's id, for example:
If I check this one:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checked_art" id="1001" />
```

I want to remove the style of

```
<div id="hide" style="display:none;" class="1001">
```

I've been trying this way with Jquery:

```
$(".checked_art").live('click',function()
{
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
   var a = "#hide ."+id;
   if(checked == 'checked')
   {
    $(a).show();
   }
   else
   {
    $(a).hide();
   }
}
```

But it just works with the first element, I want it to do that with all of them, any help? Thanks.

Comment: You should not have multiple elements with the same ID... Use class to group multiple elements with similar functionality/behavior.  ID should be used to uniquely IDentify elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".checked_art").click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

By the way, IDs must be unique.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UhsGB/)**

Comment: @EnriqueAlonsoGonzalezMeza - If you feel that this answer was helpful, please consider selecting it as the accepted answer and/or upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

First, change this line to use class rather than id:

```
<div style="display:none;" class="1001 hide">
```

Then, change your function to use the class `.hide` rather than the id `#hide` and remove the space between the `.hide` and the `.1001` selector (indicating on the same level)

```
$(".checked_art").on('click',function()
{
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
   var a = ".hide."+id;
   if(checked == 'checked')
   {
    $(a).show();
   }
   else
   {
    $(a).hide();
   }
}
```

However, a simpler code would be (based on your HTML):

```
$(".checked_art").on('click',function()
{
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).next('div.hide').hide();
    } else {
        $(this).next('div.hide').show();
    }
}
```

Or, even simpler:

```
$(".checked_art").on('click',function()
{
    $(this).next('div.hide').toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `.live()` has been deprecated. If you're using a recent version of jQuery, you should use `.on()`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".checked_art", function() {
     // ...
});
```

Also, IDs must be unique. Therefore, you should change the make the "hide" identifier a `class` attribute rather than a `id` attribute.

Furthermore, your `id` and `class` attributes should begin with a letter, not a number. You can fix this by prefixing each of your attributes that begin with a number with a common string, such as "e." For example, you would change "1001" to "e1001".

Anyway, your problem is the space between the `id` and the `class`. This:

```
var a = "#hide ."+id;
```

Should be this:

```
var a = ".hide."+id;
```